# Require cant find image path to import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

I am attempting to dynamically import images based on a random and language select.
This is a code refactor so the old project this code worked fine.

It cannot find the module and errors out.
I am wondering what the issue could be and what I need to do to fix it.

```
const BackgroundAnimation = () => {
  const currentList = useSelector((state) => state.list.currentList);
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('url("")');
  const [nextUrl, setNextUrl] = useState("");

  const getBackgroundUrl = () => {
    const languageBG = getRandomLangCode();
    const basePath = "../../assets/backgrounds/";
    const src = require(`${basePath}desktop/bg-${languageBG}.jpg`);
    setNextUrl(src);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getBackgroundUrl();
  }, []);

  // Animation Loop
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAnimate(!animate);
      getBackgroundUrl();
    }, 6000);
  }, [animate]);

  //Static Background
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentList !== null && window.innerWidth <= 767) {
      const language = languagesBGKey[currentList.language.toLowerCase()];
      const languagesList = languages[language];
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (languagesList.length - 1 - 0) + 0
      );
      const languageBG = languagesList[randomIndex][1];
      const src = require(`${basePath}mobile/bg-${languageBG}.jpg`);
      const url = `url(${src})`;

      setUrl(url);
    }
  }, [currentList]);

  return (
    <>
      <img
        style={{ opacity: 0 }}
        src={nextUrl}
        onLoad={() => {
          setUrl(`url(${nextUrl})`);
        }}
        onError={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
        }}
      />
      <div
        id="backgroundAnimation"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: url,
        }}
      ></div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Which line is the code failing on? And do the images exist for all the possible combinations of language codes the `getRandomLangCode` function returns?

Comment: Please include error details and any debugging details you've already done. This looks like a code dump and you expect someone else to debug it for you. Can you include the working version you are refactoring from, for comparison?

Comment: Errors out on Line 15... Error is Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/backgrounds/desktop/bg-en-AU.jpg'. All the images exist. I need to know why require is not working to find the file. All potential directory path combinations do not work either.

Comment: Can you create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with the `BackgroundAnimation` component and a single image to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried to put require in the src of img directly. i think you can't pass require to setState. try this if it works:

```js
const src = `${basePath}desktop/bg-${languageBG}.jpg`;

return (
  <>
    <img
      style={{ opacity: 0 }}
      src={require(nextUrl)}
      onLoad={() => {
        setUrl(`url(${nextUrl})`);
      }}
      onError={(e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```